# calculating delta Quaternion with threejs

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, quaternions

I am trying to calculate the delta quaternion of the `startOrientation` and the `endOrientation`. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo6kxjdx/6/#&togetherjs=fuxKkLbLfH) demonstrates my problem.

First, I calculate the delta quaternion and then it is multiplied with the `endOrientation` to get the `startOrientation` but its not working. The rotation of the cube is always wrong.

Uncomment line 37 to see the correct rotation of the cube. Any ideas how to compute the delta?

Comment: Where is the fiddle?

Comment: Will try and solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's examine what you (seemingly want to) compute. You start with

```
gyro = start^(-1)*end
```

and then set the scene rotation to

```
scene = end*gyro = end*start^(-1)*end
```

As you can see, this product is far from being the desired `start` quaternion. From the expectation that

```
start == scene = end*gyro
```

you would need to compute

```
gyro = end^(-1)*start
```

that is, exchange `end` and `start` in your current computation of `gyro`.

---

Also explore which of the quaternion methods are self-modifying (they all are if the result is a quaternion, with the exception of `.clone()` naturally).

The `.inverse()` method equal to `.conjugate().normalize()` falls into that class so that

```
var gyroTrackingDelta=endOrientation.inverse();
```

first inverts `endOrientation` and then shares the reference with `gyroTrackingDelta` introducing strange side effects in the further computation. A working variant that should avoid unwanted self-modification is

```
var gyroTrackingDelta=endOrientation.clone().inverse();
gyroTrackingDelta.multiply(startOrientation);

scene.quaternion.copy(endOrientation).multiply(gyroTrackingDelta);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to use THREE.Quaternion.slerp?

Comment: this should be a comment